# How to change intel BIOS screen from Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: splash-screen, ubuntu-11.04, bios

I have dell voestro 220s series desktop computer with BIOS version : 1.2.2. Ubuntu 11.04 is installed on it. At the time of system boot it shows Dell voestro and Intel logo on the screen. I want to change this intel and dell voestro BIOS splash screen. I got the solution for widows system but I want to change it from my ubuntu 11.04 system. How is it possible ?
Thanks
amar

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only way to do this is by changing the BIOS. Either you dump the original BIOS image (using for example a Linux live image with [flashrom](http://flashrom.org), like [sysrescuecd](http://www.sysresccd.org/)) and open it with a HexEditor to search where the image is located (it's probably a Bitmap image), or you can consider changing the BIOS into an open source one (like [Coreboot](http://www.coreboot.org) + [SeaBIOS](http://www.seabios.org)) and rebuild them to include a custom image (see [this page](http://www.coreboot.org/SeaBIOS#Adding_a_graphical_.22bootsplash.22_image) for more info).

I should warn you that neither option is easy. The first involves low level "hacking" and tinkering (and is possibly dangerous), while the second depends mainly on if your motherboard is supported (unfortunately, most motherboards for Intel processors aren't) and how familiar you are with compiling stuff in Linux.

Hope this helps. =)